# Распарсить строку с различными разделителями в массив

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl, split

Добрый день, я новичок в Perl есть большой файл в котором содержаться строки вида:

```
600:****:00:9100:Блаблабла (THEK+000008+0000009+0000229103+000000+0000000+0000000000+000000+0000000+0000000000
```

Как лучше распарсить в массив если сначала разделитель ":" затем "+"?
Во всех строках одинаковое количество символов. И в каждом столбце количество знаков так же не изменно. Может быть есть способ присвоить по элементу массива по типу:

```
array[0] => "600"
array[1] => ":****"
array[2] => ":00"
array[3] => ":9100"
array[4] => ":Блаблабла (THEK"
array[5] => "+000008"
arrayp[6] => "+0000009"
....
```

Comment: Покажите что именно должно быть на выходе. Правильно понимаю, что для данного случая такой массив строк: `[ "600", "****", "00", "9100", "Блаблабла", "THEK","000008",...` ]?

Comment: По позициям можно вырезать  помощью `substr()`, но будет довольно громоздко описывать каждое поле. Если определится какие знаки-буквы могут содержатся только в значениях и какие считать разделителями, то можно и split ...

Comment: substr() работает в моем случае, но думал есть, что то более элегантное.

Comment: @EvgeniyA Ну substr можно записать элегантно ... сейчас подумаю как :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если разделителя всего 2 и их не может быть в самих данных, то простой способ:

```
@array=split( /(?=[:+])/, $string );
```

За счет не захватывающей проверки `(?=)` сам разделитель включается в следующее поле данных. [Пример на ideone](http://ideone.com/pIa45T)

Если данные все таки более сложные и единственный признак это позиции подстрок, то в короткой форме `substr()` можно применить так:

```
@array=map {my($s,$l)=split/:/; substr($string,$s,$l)}
        qw(0:3 3:5);
```

Тут пары 0:3, 3:5 - это смещение:количество_символов очередного поля.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Data::Dumper;

my $l = '600:****:00:9100:Блаблабла (THEK+000008+0000009+0000229103+000000+0000000+0000000000+000000+0000000+0000000000';

$l =~ s/\+/_/; # первый + заменим на _

my @d  = split /_/, $l; # затем разобъём строку на две части, 
                        # с разделителями ':' и '+' в каждой

my @d1 = map { ':'.$_ } split /:/, $d[0];  # разобъём первую часть по ':', 
                                           # добавляя ':' перед полученными элементами
my @d2 = map { '+'.$_ } split /\+/, $d[1]; # аналогично для второй части

@d = (@d1, @d2); # объеденим результаты
$d[0] =~ s/://;  # удалим у первого элемента ':'

print Dumper \@d;
```

Comment: Отличное решение.

Comment: @EvgeniyA оно, думаю, просто более понятное, за счёт пояснений, но вариант ответа от Mike более элегантен и лаконичен, поэтому я предлагаю пометить верным его вариант, а не мой. Там просто нужно почитать про проверки (?=...), которые не захватывают подходящие под них символы в результат, за счёт чего разделитель не теряется. Подробнее про проверки можно посмотреть здесь http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use DDP;

my $string = '600:****:00:9100:Блаблабла  (THEK+000008+0000009+0000229103+000000+0000000+0000000000+000000+0000000+0000000000';
my ( $s1, $s2, $s3, @all ) = split( /[\s:(]+/, $string );

say "$s1, $s2, $s3";
p @all;
```

Comment: Отлично, но не много не то, что нужно. В вопросе подредактировал, в каком виде нужно получить данные.

Comment: @EvgeniyA А в `array[4]` перед Блаблабла двоеточия не должно быть ?

Comment: Тогда я плохо понимаю зачем нам вообще эти `:` и `+`, если по условиям мы точно знаем кол-во подстрок для каждого разделителя. Или не знаем?

Comment: @Mike да должно быть двоеточие, исправил.